# How can I reload an iFrame without the page loading icon?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, refresh, reload

This seems to work in Chrome well, but I have this iframe displaying content from a mysql table and I want to refresh it every 10 seconds, how can I do this without the user knowing the iframe is being reloading? (No loading icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript, you could have two iframes which share the load. When one fully loads, it swaps its position with the other iframe so the user never sees the load.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/NZjL8/1/

For the demo I have it refresh every 5 seconds.

Comment: Will it be visible when the Iframe reloads? And how can I set it to refresh every 10 seconds?

Comment: In firefox this still makes the icon spin.

Answer (score 1):

in header if iframe page , you can use  html meta tag instead of javascript.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x" />

Example for 10 second 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

Comment: Would X be the ID of the iFrame?

Comment: x is number ,represent second

Comment: At least in firefox (tested with 6.01) this also makes the tab loading indication spin...